# Can't Match Dates in VBA

Tags: vba, date, match

My code is:

```
Application.Match(DateValue(x),dat,0)
```

and it's returning Error 2042

In the Watches I can see that:

> The value of x is 02/01/2015 and it is a Variant/Date
>
> The values ox DateValue(x) is 02/01/2015 and it is a Variant/Date
>
> The value of dat(0) is #02/01/2015# and it is of the type Date

Any insights on why I'm getting th #N/A error ?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Also I'd like the return of the match function, since dat is an array. Thanks !

Comment: Unless formatted correctly datevalue gives the numeric value of the date, not the date.  Use cdate(x) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottCraner but unfortunately the result remained the same ! event if I use cdate(x) and or cdate(dat). Any other ideas ? I'll attach a picture to see if it helps clarifying.

Comment: on another website they proposed using clong(x).  Try that.  If it does not work I believe Jeeped's answer may be the way to go

Comment: weirdly enough it says the clong function is not defined ! Thanks for the effort !

Comment: @PedroBraz sorry my bad. it should be clng(x).  I thought long and typed the o by habit.

Comment: my bad for being that narrow ! but the error remains the same. thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the `dat` elements to retrieve the position you would normally return with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
Sub var_date_lookup()

    Dim x As Variant, dat As Variant, d As Long

    ReDim dat(0)
    For d = -3 To 5
        dat(UBound(dat)) = Date + d
        ReDim Preserve dat(0 To UBound(dat) + 1)
    Next d
    ReDim Preserve dat(0 To UBound(dat) - 1)  'trim off the last unused redim expansion

    x = Date
    For d = LBound(dat) To UBound(dat)
        Debug.Print dat(d)
        If x = dat(d) Then Debug.Print "found " & x & " at " & d
    Next d

End Sub
```